# How can I stop keyboard backlight from lighting up when logging out and back in

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

On my user I have my keyboard backlight set to off pretty much all the time. But it seems like the default setting is 'on', because when I go to the Login window, to lock my laptop when I leave it for a bit, the backlight is on again.

When I log back in, it still doesn't adjust to my previous settings (even though it seems to store it) I need to adjust the backlight to +1 (because it remembers my previous setting as 0, or off) and then back down to off to make it turn off again.

Any ideas on how to fix this minor annoyance?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty common issue: [1](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45602/how-do-i-completely-disable-automatic-keyboard-backlighting-on-macbook-pro-with) [2](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35736/os-x-lion-suppresses-users-settings-for-the-keyboard-backlight?rq=1) [3](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59177/how-can-i-permanently-disable-the-mac-keyboard-backlight)

Comment: Well, I posted this even though I found those threads, since I didn't think they were exactly the same. "Automatically illuminate keyboard in low light" is off in my preferences since way back. It's just as if it switches to the "default setting" when I lock OSX, and when I load my own by logging back in it doesn't apply them until I change them.